# Measure of left open interval in $R^2$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I just started self study probability using Rick Durrett Probability Theory and example and on page 6, I am assuming I'm on $(\mathbb{R},\sigma(\mathbb{R}),\mu)$ And the page has the following equality

> $\mu((a_1,b_1]\times(a_2,b_2])=\mu((-\infty,b_1]\times(-\infty,b_2]-\mu((-\infty,a_1]\times(-\infty,b_2]-\mu((-\infty,b_1]\times(-\infty,a_2]+\mu((-\infty,a_1]\times(-\infty,a_2]$

Visually I think it makes sense for the two subtraction in the middle but I don't see why add $\mu((-\infty,a_1]\times(-\infty,a_2]$ at the end. Isnt $(a_1,b_1]\times(a_2,b_2]$ just a rectangle region? It must be something stupid I am missing here. But I really dont see why the equality holds here. Can someone point it out for me?

Comment: Hint: What can say about $ \mu((-\infty,b_1]\times(-\infty,b_2]-\mu((-\infty,a_1]\times(-\infty,b_2]$ and $\mu((-\infty,b_1]\times(-\infty,a_2]-\mu((-\infty,a_1]\times(-\infty,a_2]$? And what do you get when you subtract the second from the first?

Comment: @geetha290krm okay! thank you! this makes more sense. I should be more creative maybe cant believe I spent 2 hours on this equality.